# does android L need another programming language?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've started learning java for android app development. Recently I heared that android annoumced a new version of android which is called "android L" and there are some thing new and some thing removed like hardware buttons.
I was wondering if there is a new language for development or no? I didnt find any resources focused on the development area of android L. And heared Android L has brought material design which some one say its a new language and some one say no its a new design. Now I confused with new version of android the development features availible in it which most differ from previous versions.

Comment: And mosts of the sites like android developer is under sanction here I cant refer to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android L still uses Java as the main programming language and it still uses the android SDK.  The main change from a programmatic perspective will be new apis that will be added

Comment: What new api for example?

Comment: Here is an overview of the apis http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html

Comment: Its forbidden here in iran. I cannot visit the site

Comment: @user3840019 use a proxy website web browser (Google "proxy web browser) or download a proxy web browser such as Tor.

Answer (score 0):

You are very confused. Android L is a new version of Android, as Android 4.4 or Android 4.3.

The difference with others versions of Android is the visual design.